# GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F

Tags: android, serialization, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

My Android app serializes objects (with `ObjectOutputStream`). Each time I deserialice one (with `ObjectInputStream`), I get lots of debug messages like this:

```
01-20 06:44:22.274: D/dalvikvm(2204): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/HashMap;.loadFactor:F
```

This happens in Android 2.3 but not 4.2. Coincidentally, performance in Android 2.3 is quite bad and the app gets out of memory quickly.

What does this warning mean exactly? Is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: This question appears to be about a similar or the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471262/hashmap-de-serialization?rq=1. Yet, the answer talks about images (which is not my case) and the warning message is left unexplained.

Comment: Another question that mentions the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631686/android-hashtable-serialization?rq=1. However, this one is serialising/deserializing objects between different architectures. In my case, it's the app who does both.